# ImageMagick composite two images and fill transparent data with original data

Tags: c, imagemagick, transparent, composite, magickwand

I have two 256X256 images, one has full purple background and the other has some of it transparent.

[image] [image]

I want to copy the second image into the first image, so that the transparent data from the second image is filled by the data from the first image, resulting this:

[image]

My attempt of doing so ended with the entire first image replaced by the second image. I used the `OverCompositeOp` operator: 
`MagickCompositeImage(wand1, wand2, OverCompositeOp, MagickFalse, 0, 0);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have the two images swapped. You need to overlay the transparent one on top of the opaque one. This assumes they both are the same size. In ImageMagick 7 command line, this works fine.

```
magick purple.png blue_transparent.png -compose over -composite result.png
```

[image]

For ImageMagick 6, replace `magick` with `convert`